# How to solve not found error in heroku after deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, heroku

I'm tried to upload a MERN stack project on `heroku`, when I push my project then does not show me any error, but after that when I tried to open my app then show me error like this:

[image]

Then when I see on `heroku logs` show me error like this:

```
2021-04-02T04:39:53.640765+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-04-02T04:39:53.673306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-02T04:39:53.673901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-02T04:39:53.688128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! react-boiler-plate@1.0.0 start: `node server/index.js`
2021-04-02T04:39:53.688366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-02T04:39:53.688645+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-02T04:39:53.688864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the react-boiler-plate@1.0.0 start script.
2021-04-02T04:39:53.689072+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-02T04:39:53.702373+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-02T04:39:53.702750+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-02T04:39:53.702956+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-02T04_39_53_691Z-debug.log
2021-04-02T04:39:53.801523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-02T04:39:57.606025+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-02T04:39:57.606043+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-boiler-plate@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-02T04:39:57.606044+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/index.js
2021-04-02T04:39:57.606044+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-02T04:39:59.617643+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T04:39:59.617704+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-04-02T04:39:59.618588+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency        
2021-04-02T04:39:59.618717+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T04:39:59.618853+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency      
2021-04-02T04:39:59.619452+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Listening on 52400
2021-04-02T04:39:59.664202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-02T04:40:00.154607+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB Connected...
2021-04-02T04:40:02.562719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=482fc0ad-4dbf-4d68-a0b8-4ad915f0356d fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=81ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T04:40:02.564414+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:40:12.580732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=0cb0a90a-eefe-4730-97f2-58ad7601fb31 fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T04:40:12.581974+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:41:07.703010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=5195792b-17a0-4044-82a6-8e392f3bc920 fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T04:41:07.703565+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:43:56.612829+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:43:56.614507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=24d996e4-a43f-427c-89d5-a83fad29ec8e fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T04:47:24.095734+00:00 app[api]: Set NODE_ENV config vars by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T04:47:24.095734+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T04:47:24.300332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-04-02T04:47:24.302570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-04-02T04:47:26.081387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-04-02T04:47:26.273408+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-04-02T04:47:28.480334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-02T04:47:32.050957+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-02T04:47:32.050999+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-boiler-plate@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-02T04:47:32.051000+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/index.js
2021-04-02T04:47:32.051001+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-02T04:47:33.084385+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T04:47:33.084397+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-04-02T04:47:33.085117+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency        
2021-04-02T04:47:33.085232+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T04:47:33.085334+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency      
2021-04-02T04:47:33.085964+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Listening on 8465
2021-04-02T04:47:33.331113+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB Connected...
2021-04-02T04:47:33.388190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-02T04:47:34.346673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=183fcfe3-db55-4a00-b385-9d7d66f60ed4 fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T04:47:34.348398+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:48:45.968962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=2a1df37e-9697-4cf4-be41-cc907f6cb724 fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T04:48:45.969496+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:55:29.405371+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T04:55:29.405889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=b9b8b037-8c4a-4c58-9fc9-d116af2283e9 fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T05:02:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T05:02:35.128829+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7dd2269f by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T05:02:35.128829+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T05:02:35.313075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-04-02T05:02:35.315983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-04-02T05:02:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-02T05:02:36.713360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-04-02T05:02:36.983404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-04-02T05:02:39.085257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-02T05:02:42.325482+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-02T05:02:42.326048+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-boiler-plate@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-02T05:02:42.326051+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/index.js
2021-04-02T05:02:42.326053+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-02T05:02:43.565518+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T05:02:43.565529+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-04-02T05:02:43.566549+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency        
2021-04-02T05:02:43.566660+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T05:02:43.566774+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency      
2021-04-02T05:02:43.567285+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Listening on 58335
2021-04-02T05:02:43.757613+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB Connected...
2021-04-02T05:02:43.923407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-02T05:03:06.224704+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=0dfe3e56-29e2-4abd-9326-30f22a3f3a3f fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T05:03:06.226724+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
2021-04-02T05:37:05.548583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-04-02T05:37:05.550224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-04-02T05:37:06.905027+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-04-02T05:37:07.188301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-04-02T05:45:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T05:46:24.941298+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3d2e9eec by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T05:46:24.941298+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user alaminsheikh30025@gmail.com
2021-04-02T05:46:25.895329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-04-02T05:46:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-02T05:46:29.859262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-04-02T05:46:33.688119+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T05:46:33.688136+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-04-02T05:46:33.688805+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T05:46:33.688950+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-04-02T05:46:33.689117+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency       
2021-04-02T05:46:33.689750+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Listening on 3542
2021-04-02T05:46:33.946525+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB Connected...
2021-04-02T05:46:34.274995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-02T05:46:41.770270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-show.herokuapp.com request_id=c42834c5-a16c-4c12-ab34-41f2a229d0d6 fwd="116.58.200.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-04-02T05:46:41.775861+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
```

I have config file by this way:

[image]

[image]

`.dev.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI:
    "mongodb+srv://username:pass@demo.erwyk.mongodb.net/PORTFOLIO?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
};
```

`prod.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
};
```

`key.js` file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

then I have add config file on heroku:

[image]

Any Suggestion Please.

Comment: I have solved my problem

Comment: OK, can you post a detailed answer explaining *how* you did solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was problem on project config, I have solved by this way:

> Make configuration for heroku deployment

specify `npm` and `node` version for frontend deployment.[check version `npm -v` and `node -v`]

Then `npm run build` for client folder

> Put environment variable for production mode in heroku website [for me `MONGO_URI`]

then go to `server` folder inside `package.js`

add this line of code

```
script {
....
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_PRODUCTION:false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
}
```

That's it.

then go to terminal...

`heroku login`

`git init`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "bug fixed"`

`heroku git:remote -a <app_name>` (if already created a app in heroku, otherwise `heroku create`)

`git push heroku master`

`heroku open`

Hope app will run successfully,

Thank you, [if still faced any problem then let me know in the comment section]